# Are two non-Turing-recognizable languages closed under union?

Tags: turing-machines

If I have two languages that aren't Turing-recognizable, is the union between them always not T-recognizable? Why?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?  This is a dump of an exercise, not a question.  This is not a site where you copy-paste your exercise and we solve it for you -- it's a site to help answer conceptual questions that are likely to be of value to others.  We expect you to make a serious effort before asking and to show us what you have tried.  We want to help, but if you don't show us what you've tried, it's hard to tell how exactly to help you.

Comment: @D.W. if this is a copy-paste, is it wrong? It seems like a valid question on the appropriate site.

Comment: @SamB. We always expect the asker to show his/her own effort.

Comment: What if the effort has amounted to nothing? Is it not a waste of time for readers to learn why the poster is stumped? I think that concise questions have their place, this one already has two quality answers.

Comment: I had this exercise at my exam of theoretical computer science, but I didn't know how reply to this question. I already did the exam without giving an answer, so now I came here for understand the solution of this problem.

Comment: @SamB., I encourage you to take discussion of those issues to Meta.CS.  They've been discussed in the past, and you can find discussions using search -- or you could post a new question and start a new discussion.  However, this comment thread probably isn't the right place for that discussion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, sometimes you can recognize their union. As an example, take a language where it and its complement are undecidable. Then their union is decided by a TM that always says yes.

Comment: Note that "recognizable" normally means "recursively enumerable" rather than "decidable". So an undecidable set isn't necessarily unrecognizable.

Comment: The union between $EQ_{TM}$ and $\overline{EQ}_{TM}$ seems a language decidable, so I think you're right, thanks.

Comment: @David Richerby: that's true,  but I'm pretty sure that makes my result stronger, i.e. even if they're unrecognizable or undecidable, sometimes you can recognize the union.

Comment: I'm not interested to undecidable languages but to unrecognizable languages, but the statement of jmite seems right for $EQ_{TM}$ and $\overline{EQ}_{TM}$ that are both unrecognizable languages.

Answer (score 11):

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be any unrecognizable set. Let $L_1 = \{0, 2, 4, \dots\} \cup \{2n+1\mid n\in U\}$ and $L_2 = \{1,3,5, \dots\} \cup \{2n\mid n\in U\}$. $L_1$ and $L_2$ are both unrecognizable but their union is $\mathbb{N}$.